# TSQL - Collapse matching records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Code:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (ID1 INT);
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (ID1 INT, ID2 INT, DT DATE);

INSERT INTO @T1 (ID1)
VALUES (1), (2);

INSERT INTO @T2 (ID1, ID2, DT)
    SELECT 1, 100, GETDATE()
    UNION
    SELECT 1, 200, GETDATE() - 1
    UNION
    SELECT 3, 300, GETDATE()
    UNION
    SELECT 4, 200, GETDATE();
```

Query:

```
SELECT  
    T1.ID1,
    CASE 
       WHEN T2.ID2 = 100 THEN T2.DT
    END SD,
    CASE 
       WHEN T2.ID2 = 200 THEN T2.DT
    END ED
FROM
    @T1 T1
LEFT JOIN 
    @T2 T2 ON T1.ID1 = T2.ID1 AND T2.ID2 IN (100, 200);
```

Current output:

```
ID1 SD          ED
----------------------------
1   2016-09-01  NULL
1   NULL        2016-08-31
2   NULL        NULL
```

Desired output:

```
ID1 SD          ED
---------------------------
1   2016-09-01  2016-08-31
2   NULL        NULL
```

**GOAL**: to collapse both rows matching on key column(s) and get out output for each `CASE` statement columns instead of 2 separate. Note, in real query, these tables are large and I'm joining to a few other table and SELECTing a lot more descriptive columns. This query must have minimum reads/fast! (i.e. can't use temp tables/variables/CTEs and all if possible)

Comment: "can't use temp tables/variables/CTEs' ... well, what *can* you use, then? You do realize that SQL Server may choose to build temp tables in the background even if you do not explicitly do so, right?  Unless you're going to be doing a `select into` within the same database, you're going to use the tempdb, and cross a process boundary in doing so.  Also, please clarify whether you're looking to aggregate, or simply to represent all combinations - i.e., if you had `SD` of '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-02' would you want to see both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need an aggregation function:

```
SELECT  T1.ID1 ,
        MIN(CASE WHEN T2.ID2 = 100 THEN T2.DT
        END) SD ,
        MIN(CASE WHEN T2.ID2 = 200 THEN T2.DT
        END) ED
FROM    @T1 T1
        LEFT JOIN @T2 T2 ON T1.ID1 = T2.ID1
                            AND T2.ID2 IN ( 100, 200 )
GROUP BY T1.ID1;
```

If you want to avoid `GROUP BY`, you could do 2 left joins, as long as there are no duplicated rows in `@T2`:

```
SELECT  T1.ID1 ,
        T100.DT SD,
        T200.DT ED
FROM    @T1 T1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM @T2
            WHERE ID2 = 100) T100
    ON T1.ID1 = T100.ID1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM @T2
            WHERE ID2 = 200) T200
    ON T1.ID1 = T200.ID1;
```

Comment: Anyways to avoid GROUP BY/DISTINCT?

Comment: assuming there are no duplicates on @T2, you can do two left joins with the appropriate conditions

Comment: thanks! I thought about going with 2 left join route but @t2 being a huge table, I'm not sure if I want to do that...unless that's the fastest way..

Comment: @Lamak no need for subquery. you can move the condition to the on segment. it will be much shorter.

Comment: @Hamawi I know, but I prefer it that way for readability, and the optimizer will most likely generate the same execution plan

Answer (score 1):

You need to use PIVOT:

```
Select * from
(SELECT  
    T1.ID1, T2.DT, 
    CASE 
       WHEN T2.ID2 = 100 THEN 'SD'
       WHEN T2.ID2 = 200 THEN 'ED'
    END SDED
FROM
    @T1 T1
LEFT JOIN 
    @T2 T2 ON T1.ID1 = T2.ID1 AND T2.ID2 IN (100, 200)) t
Pivot (MAX(DT) FOR SDED in ([SD], [ED]) ) P
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Table design will dictate the query style to achieve your goals. Since, you opted out for group by, other options will definitely involve self table joins and various other options. Best solution should be based on following:

1. Total Time taken on the back end side for execution of queries.
2. The Query style that works the best. It will depend on your other table structures, your data needs, indexes, data size.